# Find and show only files from a specific date given

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, datetime

Basically I have a tacacs file folder with a LOT of archived files, 3 are created per day to be precise.
I'm looking to make a script where the user has to enter a date when he starts the script and it shows him the files created (or last modified) on that date.

I also plan to make it so that the user must then choose between the 3 files which one he wants to see. But for now I'm just trying to show the three files on the cli.

But my script doesn't accept the date I give it. I get each time "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" while showing me the month I entered.

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptacacs2.py", line 6, in <module>
    date_entry = input('Enter a date in YEAR, MONTH, DAY format \n')
  File "<string>", line 1
    2022 04 12
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code is:

```
import re
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime

date_entry = input('Enter a date in YEAR, MONTH, DAY format \n')
path = "/applis/tacacs/log/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

mtime = datetime(date_entry).timestamp()

list_of_files = [
    file for file in glob.glob(path + '*.gz')
        if os.path.getmtime(file) == mtime
]
print (list_of_files)
```

I don't see what causes this syntax error. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You just paste a string into `datetime` and  that's not how it works: If `date_entry` looks like `"2022 04 12"` then you'd need something like `datetime(*map(int, date_entry.split()))` to make that work? Or `datetime.strptime(date_entry, "%Y %m %d")`.

Comment: @Timus Thanks for the help, I tried but I still have the syntax error. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [Add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71883907/edit) the exact value of `date_entry` to your question (the one that leads to the error) and also add the full stacktrace (error message) to it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3? Python 2 tries to parse the the string you get using `input`, if you're on python2 use `raw_input`.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez It seems that I was using Python 2.7 instead of 3. I changed `input` to `raw input` and now I don't get any error.
But I have no output now. When I enter a date nothing happens.

Comment: @Kevin.T I updated my example to work with python2 solving the missing timestamp issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting a `SyntaxError` error. I'm guessing it's because you're using Python2 and `input` behaves differently (it tries to parse the input) for python2 you should use `raw_input`.

But the parsing of the date is incorrect.

If you want it to parse a date in a `2022,01,01` format you should use:

`datetime.strptime("2022,01,23", "%Y,%m,%d")` or if you want to be able to have the whitespace in do:

`datetime.strptime(re.sub("\s+", "", "2022, 01, 23"), "%Y,%m,%d")`

Also you probably don't want to test for equality of the timestamp, you want to check for equality of date. So I'd do:

```py
import re
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_entry = input('Enter a date in YEAR, MONTH, DAY format \n')
date = datetime.strptime(re.sub("\s+", "", date_entry), "%Y,%m,%d").date()

path = "/applis/tacacs/log/"


list_of_files = [
    file for file in glob.glob(path + '*.gz')
    if date == datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file)).date()
]
print(list_of_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you try to provide the `datetime` object a string, however, he needs integers. (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)). So first, you need to split the date you receive with the `split` method. (here I changed a bit the input so as to have a more readable and practicable sentence). Then, you need to transform the numbers as string into integers with the `map` function and finally unpack the values with the `*` to pass the arguments.

Your second problem was the use of the glob library while you already retrieved the files with the `listdir` method.

And finally, you are checking the date of the files with the timestamp with is an error because the timestamp value represent the amount of secs since Jan 01 1970 and if a file is created one second after the other, they wont have the same timestamp. So, you have to convert these timestamps into dates and then check if the dates are the same.

Here's the final result :

```py
import os

from datetime import datetime

PATH = "applis/tacacs/log/"


def is_same_date(t1, t2):
    """
    Check if the two provided timestamps represents the same date
    """
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(t1).date() == datetime.fromtimestamp(t2).date()


date_entry = map(int, input("Enter a date in 'YYYY/MM/DD' format \n").split("/"))

dirs = os.listdir(PATH)

mtime = datetime(*date_entry).timestamp()

list_of_files = [f for f in dirs if is_same_date(os.path.getmtime(PATH + f), mtime)]
print(list_of_files)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I don't have the syntax error anymore, but I have the error `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'` when trying your code. I just tried the date 2022/04/12. Any idea why ?

Comment: Working good for me locally. What is your python version ?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.12

Comment: That's the reason, the `timestamp` method doesn't exists before the version `3.3` of python. You either need to upgrade python or need to find a substitute (which can be easily found).